# Some Altair charts fade

Tags: python, altair

Updated: Changing `alt.X('yearmonthdate(TimeUTC):T'` to `alt.X('yearmonthdate(TimeUTC):O'` made the problem go away. See bottom of post.

I have four years of data of the form:

|  | TimeUTC | FlightID | DroneType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-08-22 19:35:23.024386+00:00 | 2018-08-22 19:35:23+00:00 | 663f-46fe-8887-d37895745506 | MavicPro |
| 2018-08-22 19:35:35.888933+00:00 | 2018-08-22 19:35:35+00:00 | 663f-46fe-8887-d37895745506 | MavicPro |
| 2018-08-22 20:05:06.239102+00:00 | 2018-08-22 20:05:06+00:00 | a63a-4e01-b2d2-bdecc9027049 | MavicPro |

(There is, I think, a good reason for the microseconds in the index AND the TimeUTC column, but that is for another day.)

I plot this data by year. One set of graphs using mark_bar is produced as expected. Two of the four mark_area charts are very faded and a third is somewhat faded.

[image: A "good" chart]

[image: A very faded chart]

[image: A somewhat faded chart]

```python
    chart = alt.Chart(chart_df).mark_area().encode(
        alt.X('month(TimeUTC):O', title='Month',axis=alt.AxisConfig(labelAngle=45)), 
        alt.Y('distinct(FlightID)', type='quantitative', title='Number of sUAS Operations'),
        alt.Color('DroneType', 
            type='nominal', 
            legend=alt.Legend(orient="bottom", columns=4), 
        scale=alt.Scale(domain=_domain, range=_range_))
    ).properties(
            title='Distribution of sUAS Flights by Model Over Time (Fig. 11)',
            width=400,
            height=200
        )

    chart.configure_title(
        fontSize=20,
        font='Courier',
        anchor='start',
        color='gray'
    )
```

All the charts use the same function and the data from the same data frame.

What might be causing this fade effect and how can I fix it?

Updated:

Original problem chart created with `alt.X('yearmonthdate(TimeUTC):T'`:

[image: Chart using :T]

Chart using `alt.X('yearmonthdate(TimeUTC):O'`:

[image: Chart with :O]

Comment: You mention an issue with an area chart, but your code shows a bar chart. If you want a good chance of getting your question answered, I would suggest creating a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (including a machine-readable data sample) of the problem you're seeing – otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: I fixed the code, thank you for pointing that out.

The dataset is huge. The four chunks are:

((366745, 9), (1198109, 9), (1812138, 9), (1056390, 9))

The fade effect is loosely correlated with the size of the dataset. All of my efforts to produce the effect with smaller datasets fail.

Comment: Often it’s most useful in a reproducible example to write code that generates fake data suitable for demonstrating the issue, rather than trying to use real data.

Comment: I have tried reproducing your issue with similar temporal datasets, but have not been able to do it. If you can provide a reproducible example, I'll try to help. Otherwise there's not much I can do.

Comment: Understood, and thank you very much for trying. I'll see if I can find a good way to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix, such as it is, required changing:

`alt.X('yearmonthdate(TimeUTC):T`

to

`alt.X('yearmonthdate(TimeUTC):O`